# Is every Quantum Computer working with entangled particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

**Is every Quantum Computer working with entangled particles?**

I ask this question, because entangled particles are not allways local.
I read that a Quantum Gate can be used to concatenate quantum particles.
Logically I follow out of my knowlegde till now (I am no Phisicst), that a Quantum Computer can have more then one gates with entangled particles. Is that OK?

Comment: 1. Please do not put the question solely into the title, but at least repeat it in the body of your post. 2. I do not quite understand what a "theoretical" answer is supposed to be in this case.

Comment: Dear ACuriousMind, is the answer so difficult? Actual Quantum Computing is mostly a scientific theory, in best point of view we can say the so called "running Quanten Computers" (IBM, GOOGLE) are some very exceptionel play-machines  with subatomar particles and are so expensive because they are no real functionable computers. Therefor I want constructive and not only mathematically theoretical answers.  electrons,wyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

The alternative would be to have a single monolithic system with a huge number of internal states where you implemented the computation, which is about as bad as it gets in terms of scalability. What we do, instead, is have a number of simpler subsystems (i.e. the qubits) that we put together to do the quantum computation, where the mechanism for 'putting together' is nothing more and nothing less than entanglement.

Comment: As I understand : every qubit has his own entanglement?

Comment: Entanglement is always a feature of (and assigned to) two or more quantum system. So that statement makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks, now my question is repeated!